# passing list as argument though rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm using R's [spi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPEI/SPEI.pdf) function in Python. One of the arguments ("kernel") requires a list, and I'm not sure how to pass it through when using rpy2. The R syntax would be as follows (*with* the "kernel" argument):

```
library("lmomco", lib.loc="~/lib/R_libs")
library("SPEI", lib.loc="~/lib/R_libs")

data = read.csv("rainfall_data.csv", header = FALSE)
result = spi(data, scale=10, distribution='Gamma', fit='max-lik', kernel = list(type='rectangular', shift=0))
```

My Python script so far (*without* using the "kernel" argument) is as follows:

```
import numpy as np 
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr('lmomco')
SPEI = importr('SPEI')

import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri as numpy2ri
numpy2ri.activate()

data = np.genfromtxt('rainfall_data.csv', delimiter=',')

result = np.array(SPEI.spi(data, scale=10, distribution='Gamma', fit='max-lik')[1])
```

How would one pass the kernel as a list for rpy2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating a [ListVector](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html#) from a python dictionary, then pass it into the method:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects 
...
x = robjects.ListVector({'type': 'rectangular', 'shift': 0})

result = np.array(SPEI.spi(data, scale=10, distribution='Gamma', fit='max-lik', kernel=x)[1])
```